# Dynamic subject in contact mail

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am working on a simple contact system where i need to display a value from a querystring in the subject field of the sent email.

Today has been a slow descent into madness as this has failed to work in every way i have tried.

I am using Umbraco 4.7.2 with Ubootstrap (bootstrap by twitter) and modifying the contact form found within.
Below is the cshtml of my contact form macro

```
@using System.Text
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using Bootstrap.Logic.Utils
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@{
    dynamic form = Context.Request.Form.ToDynamic();

    if (IsPost)
    {
        if (!Context.IsValidAntiForgery()) { ModelState.AddFormError(@Dictionary.InvalidPost); }
        if (MainHelper.IsEmpty(form.Name)) { ModelState.AddError("name", @Dictionary.FormNameValidation); }
        if (!MainHelper.IsEmail(form.Email)) { ModelState.AddError("email", @Dictionary.FormEmailValidation); }
        if (MainHelper.IsEmpty(form.Enquiry)) { ModelState.AddError("enquiry", @Dictionary.FormCommentValidation); }
    }

    if (!IsPost || !ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    @Html.Raw(library.RemoveFirstParagraphTag(Model.FormText.ToString()))
    <form method="post" action="@Model.Url">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>@Parameter.subject </legend>
            <div class="clearfix @Library.If(!ModelState.IsValidField("name"), "error")">
            @Html.Label(@Dictionary.FormName, "name")
            <div class="input">@Html.TextBox("name", form.Name, new { @class = "xlarge" })
            @if (!ModelState.IsValidField("name"))
            { <span class="help-inline">@string.Join(". ", @ModelState["name"].Errors)</span> }
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.Label(@Dictionary.AddressName, "address1")
            <div class="input">@Html.TextBox("address1", form.Address1, new { @class = "xlarge" })</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.Label("Add 2", "address2", new { @class = "hide" })
            <div class="input">@Html.TextBox("address2", form.Address2, new { @class = "xlarge" })</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix @Library.If(!ModelState.IsValidField("email"), "error")">
            @Html.Label(@Dictionary.FormEmail, "email")
            <div class="input">@Html.TextBox("email", form.Email, new { @type = "email", @class = "xlarge" })
            @if (!ModelState.IsValidField("email"))
            { <span class="help-inline">@string.Join(". ", @ModelState["email"].Errors)</span> }
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix @Library.If(!ModelState.IsValidField("name"), "error")">
            @Html.Label(@Dictionary.FormComment, "enquiry")
            <div class="input">@Html.TextArea("enquiry", form.Enquiry, new { @rows = 5, @cols = 25, @class = "xlarge" })
            @if (!ModelState.IsValidField("enquiry"))
            { <span class="help-inline">@string.Join(". ", @ModelState["enquiry"].Errors)</span> }
            </div>
            </div>
            @Context.GetAntiForgeryHtml()
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions">
            <button id="SubmitForm" type="submit" class="btn">@Dictionary.Send</button>  
        </div>
    </form>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(@Dictionary.FormValidationSummary, new { @class = "alert-message block-message error" })
    }
    else
    {
        var ok = SendForm(form, @Parameter.subject);
        if (!ok)
        {
            <div id="errorMailSettings">
                @Model.ErrorMessage
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            // Set Thankyou text from our contact node
            <div id="thankYou">
                <h2>@Model.ThankYouHeaderText</h2>
                @Model.ThankYouMessageText
            </div>
        }
    }
}

@functions 
{
    public bool SendForm(dynamic form, string queryParam)
    {
        // Get the variables from the form and set them in strings
        string strName = Library.StripHtml(form.Name).ToString();
        string strAddressLine1 = Library.StripHtml(form.Address1).ToString();
        string strAddressLine2 = Library.StripHtml(form.Address2).ToString();
        string strEmailFrom = Library.StripHtml(form.Email).ToString();
        string strMessage = Library.StripHtml(form.Enquiry).ToString();

        // Lets set the values passed in from the Macro
        string strEmailTo = Model.EmailTo.ToString();
        string strEmailSubject = queryParam;

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var strTime = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", now);
        var strDate = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", now);

        // Let's Replace the placeholders in the email message body
        var strEmailBody = new StringBuilder(Model.EmailBody.ToString());
        strEmailBody.Replace("[Name]", strName); // Find and Replace [Name]
        strEmailBody.Replace("[AddressLine1]", strAddressLine1); // Find and Replace [AddressLine1]
        strEmailBody.Replace("[AddressLine2]", strAddressLine2); // Find and Replace [AddressLine2]
        strEmailBody.Replace("[Email]", strEmailFrom); // Find and Replace [Email]
        strEmailBody.Replace("[Message]", strMessage); // Find and Replace [Message]
        strEmailBody.Replace("[Time]", strTime); // Find and Replace [Time]
        strEmailBody.Replace("[Date]", strDate); // Find and Replace [Date]

        // Now the email is sent out to the owner, lets send out an email
        // to let the user know we have recieved their email & will respond shortly
        string strEmailReplySubject = Model.EmailReplySubject.ToString();
        var strEmailReplyBody = new StringBuilder(Model.EmailReplyBody.ToString());
        strEmailReplyBody.Replace("[Name]", strName); // Find and Replace [Name]

        return MainHelper.TrySendMail(strEmailTo, strEmailSubject, strEmailBody.ToString()) && MainHelper.TrySendMail(strEmailFrom, strEmailReplySubject, strEmailReplyBody.ToString());
    }
}
```

(Wall of code i know but i figure more info is better than less)

This results in the display of the querystring from macro parameter via @Parameter.subjet in the legend field, but when i try further down in the send function to set the string strEmailSubject to @Parameter.subject i just get the empty field in the email.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Have you added the parameter "subject" to the actual macro?

Comment: yes, and i can see that the parameter works in the part of the macro where i define the fieldset as i use it for the value of the legend tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this problem doing the following:

I knew that @Parameter.subject would allow me to place the querystring in the form, so i made a new textbox in the form to hold the parameter and then stripped it out ala 
Library.StripHtml(form.Subject).ToString();
and used this to call the SendForm function

Answer (score 1):

Aparently Parameter doesn't exist within the function context. I would suggest passing it in as a argument to the function:

```
...

var ok = SendForm(form, Parameter.subject);

...

public bool SendForm(dynamic form, string subject)
{
    ...

    string strEmailSubject = subject;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i just tried but there is still nothing coming trough. (updated my code above)